# wxStyledTextCtrl sample program fails at runtime

Tags: wxwidgets

The wxStyledTextCtrl sample program fails at runtime

../msw/window.cpp(3750): assert "wclass" failed in MSWCreate():
failed to register window class?

wxWidgets 3.0.1 on windows

building with code::blocks

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  I was linking with the debug version of the STC library.  Linking with the release version works OK.